# How to use BeautifulSoup to save data to csv File?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have following data with parent div [col-md-8] in which odd div[row] contains Questions and even div[row] contains Answers.In total I have 15 Questions.I have a CSV file in which fields are [Questions,a,b,c,d].What I want is to get data from html and save it to CSV file.

```
<div class="col-md-8"> <!-- Parent Div Starts --!>
    <div class="alert"></div>
    <div class="row">  <!-- Question 1 Starts --!>
       <div class=" col-md-8">
       <strong>1</strong>
        Every Polynomial has
       </div>
   </div><!-- Question 1 Ends --!>
   <div class="row"> <!-- Question 1 Option Starts -- !>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(a) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(b) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(c) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(d) three 
           zeros
       </div>         
  </div><!-- Question 1 Option Ends -- !>
  <div class="row"><!-- Question 2 Starts --!>
      <div class=" col-md-8">
        <strong>2</strong>
         Every Equation has
      </div>
  </div><!-- Question 2 Ends --!>
    <div class="row">!-- Question 2 Option Ends -- !>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(a) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(b) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(c) three 
           zeros
       </div>
       <div class=" col-md-6">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(d) three 
           zeros
       </div>         
  </div><!-- Question 2 Option Ends -- !>
  <!-- Like This I have 15 Questions and Options For Each Question -
  -!> 
</div> <!-- Parent Div Ends --!>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
all_div_row = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row'}) # get all div whose class='row'
with open('question_answer.csv','wb') as f: # Change the 'wb' to 'w' mode in python 3.x
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Questions','a','b','c','d']) #write header
    for question, answer in zip(all_div_row[::2],all_div_row[1::2]): # get question in odd div, and answer in even div
        question_text = [" ".join(question.text.strip().split())]
        answer_text = [" ".join(div.text.strip().replace("\n", "").split()) for div in answer.find_all('div')]
        writer.writerow(question_text+answer_text)
```

The file `question_answer.csv` will be:

```
Questions,a,b,c,d
1 Every Polynomial has,(a) three zeros,(b) three zeros,(c) three zeros,(a) three zeros
2 Every Equation has,(a) three zeros,(b) three zeros,(c) three zeros,(a) three zeros
```